# Typescript 2.0 typeof null variable is undefined

Tags: typescript, null, undefined

I am newly learning Typescript and I run through a strange behavior, I was trying to declare two variables one `null` and the other `undefined` as it is a new feature introduced in Typescript 2.0.

```
let myNullVar :null;
let myNullVar2 : undefined;

console.log(typeof myNullVar);
console.log(typeof myNullVar2);
```

I was expecting to see this output:

```
null
undefined
```

But it was:

```
undefined
undefined
```

More, when I do this:

```
if(typeof myNullVar === 'null'){
    console.log('null');
}
else if (typeof myNullVar === 'undefined'){
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

I get `undefined`

Is null the same thing as undefined in Typescript? if yes, what is the purpose of having both?

Comment: `:` doesn't do assignment, its just a type annotation

Comment: I edited the question it was the typeof that was missing

Comment: @hvd You are right, re-edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type annotations don't affect runtime behavior and `typeof` is a runtime construct.

The value of an uninitialized variable is `undefined`, and `typeof undefined` is always `"undefined"`. Note that this is a *string*, not the same as the value `undefined` itself.

Since it's about to come up, `typeof null` is `"object"`.

Comment: When the code gets transpiled to JS there is no types set on my two variables (which is the purpose of TS). So when I get the types of these two variables, no matter what type I declare them to be in TS, they will always be undefined as long as they are not initialized to a value, is that right?

Comment: That's right. JavaScript variable bindings themselves don't have types, only values.