# Typescript property 'property' does not exist on type 'void | ISample

Tags: javascript, typescript

According to Typescript `void` is a [supertype](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void) of the `null` and `undefined` types. So, a function with void type could return `null` or `undefined`.

Just the problem is when I try to compile using the `typeof val !== 'undefined'` and `val !== undefined`. The second is failing but the first one is working.

According to the documentation `typeof null` should be `object` and `typeof undefined` is `undefined` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49947791/2389232))

So, which is the reason because the first method is compiling and the second one is failing? It doesn't have a sense for me.

```
interface IFace {
  data: string;
}

function sample(): void | IFace { // void could be null or undefined
  return null;
}

let value = sample();

if( value !== undefined )
    console.log(value.data); // It fails because value could be null

if( typeof value !== 'undefined' )
    console.log(value.data); // Why is it working? typeof value could be object (because null)
```

[See DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20IFace%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20sample()%3A%20void%20%7C%20IFace%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20void%20could%20be%20null%20or%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20value%20%3D%20sample()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif(%20value%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(value.data)%3B%20%2F%2F%20It%20fails%20because%20value%20could%20be%20null%0D%0A%0D%0Aif(%20typeof%20value%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined'%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(value.data)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Why%20is%20it%20working%3F%20typeof%20value%20could%20be%20object%20(because%20null)%0D%0A)

It seems `typeof value !== 'undefined'` is interpreted as an object (because `typeof null` and `typeof IFace` are objects). But null objects don't have data field there, so should it be failing?

**UPDATED**
According to [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) with `strictNullChecks` option to `true` could be solved this problem:

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void). So, whereas T and T | undefined are considered synonymous in regular type checking mode (because undefined is considered a subtype of any T), **they are different types in strict type checking mode, and only T | undefined permits undefined values. The same is true for the relationship of T to T | null**.

But I don't know why `typeof` is working with `strictNullChecks` to `false`. According to [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29405#issuecomment-454085408) the reason because `typeof` is working it seems to be that the compiler doesn't special-case `typeof` in an expression for the purpose of type checking.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question but note that `x == null` is `true` when `x` is *either* `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @Pointy Yes, x is either `null` or `undefined` so if I check with `typeof` a variable as `undefined`, that variable could be `null` and maybe it is not an object.

Comment: @Pointy the question is why does TS now show an error about the second check. For the first one it correctly says that `value` could be `null` ( when `!== undefined`), and thus accessing the `data` field will lead to an error. The second check, however, *succeeds*, and TS is apparently not concerned that `typeof value !== 'undefined'` still doesn't cover the value `null`. Even more amusingly, if you change that check to `typeof value !== 'object'` TS correctly tells you that `value` would be a `void` type and still doesn't have `data`.

Comment: It seems `typeof value !== 'undefined'` is interpreted as object (because `typeof null` and `typeof IFace` are objects). But `null` objects don't have `data` field :s

Comment: I agree that apparently that's the problem but still...why? Surely TypeScript of all things should be aware that `typeof value !== 'undefined'` will result in `null | object` same as `vale !== undefined`. I guess the evaluation is something like `value -> null | undefined | IFace` and if it's not `undefined` it leaves the other two. The `typeof` operator must then obviously be doing something different `typeof value -> "undefined" | "object"` but "object" is not considered `null | not-null`

Comment: Huh, being explicit about `null` seems to be [completely ignored by TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20IFace%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20sample()%3A%20null%20%7C%20IFace%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20value%20%3D%20sample()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20console.log(value.data)%3B%0D%0A) `value -> null | IFace` is allowed to be dereferenced freely.

Comment: It seems it has `strictNullChecks` to false ([check this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html)) and the compiler doesn't special-case `typeof` in an expression for the purpose of type checking [see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29405#issuecomment-454085408)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation.

> Union types can be a bit tricky here, but it just takes a bit of intuition to get used to. If a value has the type A | B, we only know for certain that it has members that both A and B have. In this example, Bird has a member named fly. We can’t be sure whether a variable typed as Bird | Fish has a fly method. If the variable is really a Fish at runtime, then calling pet.fly() will fail.

In your example void does not have property 'data'. So it is not recognized in the following:

```
if( value !== undefined ) 
    console.log(value.data);
```

You can also update it as follows to make it work:

```
if( (<IFace>value).data !== undefined )
    console.log((<IFace>value).data);
```

Then there is something called as Type Guards that come into the picture. And typescript recognizes typeof as one of the type guards.

> These typeof type guards are recognized in two different forms: typeof v === "typename" and typeof v !== "typename", where "typename" must be "number", "string", "boolean", or "symbol". While TypeScript won’t stop you from comparing to other strings, the language won’t recognize those expressions as type guards.

Here is [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) for more information.

Comment: I know the Type Guards. If you just check the data property, `value` could be `undefined` and you will have problems. Type Guards are useful on some occasions but in the end, you need to think that you are forcing the type for the variable.